# Analytic solution to a second order nonlinear ODE involving $\operatorname{sech}^2(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrable-systems

I am trying to look for an analytic solution to the following equation

$\frac{1}{4D} (y')^2 -\frac{1}{2}y'' = -n(n+1)A\operatorname{sech}^2(\frac{x}{b})$

with $A>0$, $D>0$ and $b>0$ and $n>1$ an integer. This equation is obtained from trying to find the equivalent Fokker-Planck equation for the Poschl-Teller Schrodinger equation. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential) suggests a relation to KdV hence my hopes that it might be analytically solvable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute
\begin{equation}
 y(x) = -2 D \log z(x),
\end{equation}
the ODE transforms to
\begin{equation}
 D z'' = -n(n+1)A\, \text{sech}^2(x/b)\,z. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now, introducing
\begin{equation}
 \xi(x) = \tanh x/b,
\end{equation}
we see that
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} x^2} = \frac{1-\xi^2}{b^2}\left((1-\xi^2) \frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} \xi^2} - 2 \xi \frac{\text{d} z}{\text{d} \xi}\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \text{sech}^2 x/b = 1 - \xi^2.
\end{equation}
Using this new variable, the ODE $(1)$ transforms to
\begin{equation}
(1-\xi^2) \frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} \xi^2} - 2 \xi \frac{\text{d} z}{\text{d} \xi}+ n(n+1) \frac{A}{D} b^2 z = 0.
\end{equation}
This is the [Legendre equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.2), with standard solutions given by Legendre functions $P_\nu(\xi)$ and $Q_\nu(\xi)$, where
\begin{equation}
 \nu = \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4 \frac{A}{D} b^2 n(n+1)}}{2}.
\end{equation}
For more information, see the relevant [DLMF entry](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14).